# Data attributes in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to add an HTML5 data-attribute to my blazor component:

```xml
<div data-is-loaded=@_isLoaded>
  ...
</div>

@code {
  private bool _isLoaded = false;
  protected override void OnInitialized() => _isLoaded = true;
}
```

But that renders: `<div data-is-loaded="">`.

I also tried:

- splatting to a dynamically created dictionary

  ```xml
  <div @attributes=@(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-is-loaded", _isLoaded } })>
  ```
- and using a property instead of a field

...with the same result.

I know the variable contains the value I expect, because this does work:

```xml
<div class=@(_isLoaded ? "loaded" : "")>
```

As you can see, this is not data passed into the component. It's just some basic value I want to add as a data-attribute (which as I'm sure you've guessed, is a way to signal something to the component's associated javascript).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML attributes must be strings, so the issue can be solved by converting `_isLoaded` to a string:

```html
<div data-is-loaded=@(_isLoaded ? "true" : "false")>
  ...
</div>

@code {
  private bool _isLoaded = false;
  protected override void OnInitialized() => _isLoaded = true;
}
```

You can change the strings to fit what you need.

Here is the example on blazorfiddle (you may need to use chrome):
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/mj2vt94g

Comment: I was so used to the razor compiler coercing data types in various places, it didn't even occur to me that it could be something so simple. Thanks!